# The specified 'scope' is invalid. while refreshing token

Tags: openiddict

I'm migrating from id4 to openiddict. So far everything is working well.
Authorizing and getting a token via the authorization_code grant works fine.

Except for when I want to refresh a token.

I'm getting an `'invalid_grant'` error with the description `'The specified 'scope' is invalid. while refreshing token.'`

The refresh token request payload looks like this:

```
grant_type: refresh_token
scope: openid roles offline_access
refresh_token: *[redacted]
client_id: js
```

server config:

```
.AddServer(options =>
{
    options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

    options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/authorize")
                      .SetTokenEndpointUris("/token")
                      .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/logout")
                      .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/userinfo");

    options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
           .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

    options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Profile,
                            Scopes.Roles,
                            Scopes.OfflineAccess,
                            Scopes.OpenId,
                            Scopes.Email,
                            "api1");

    options.RegisterClaims(Claims.Role,
                            Claims.Profile,
                            Claims.Name,
                            Claims.Subject,
                            "user_type");

    options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
        Convert.FromBase64String("DRjd/GnduI3Efzen9V9BvbNUfc/VKgXltV7Kbk9sMkY=")));

    // Register the signing credentials.
    options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

    options.UseAspNetCore()
                           .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                           .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough();

    options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
})    
.AddValidation(options =>
{
    options.UseLocalServer();
    options.UseAspNetCore();
});
```

Application client

```
  await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
        {
            ClientId = "js",
            ConsentType = ConsentTypes.External,
            DisplayName = "angular client PKCE",
            DisplayNames =
                    {
                        [CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("th-TH")] = "Application client"
                    },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                    {
                        new Uri("https://localhost.domain.com")
                    },
            RedirectUris =
                    {
                        new Uri("https://localhost.domain.com/callback")
                    },
            Permissions =
                    {
                        Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                        Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
                        Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                        Permissions.Endpoints.Revocation,
                        Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                        Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken,
                        Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
                        Permissions.Scopes.Profile,
                        Permissions.Scopes.Roles,
                        Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "api1"
                    },
            Requirements =
                    {
                        Requirements.Features.ProofKeyForCodeExchange
                    }
        });
```

relevant openid config:

```
"scopes_supported": [
   "openid",
   "offline_access",
   "profile",
   "roles",
   "email",
   "api1"
],
```

I did disable accesstoken encryption because the angular client reads the sub to get the userId. Could this be the problem? I'm not seeing any scope missing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem and must have been tired. When setting scopes in identity I forgot the `roles` scope.

```
identity.SetScopes(new[] { "api1", "profile", "openid", "offline_access" });
```

fixed it by just setting:

```
identity.SetScopes(request.GetScopes());
```

so the error was pretty spot on, would've been nice to have the offending scope though.